# "Average" of multiple quaternions?

Tags: math, quaternions

I'm trying to make the switch from matrices to quaternions for skeletal animation in my OpenGL program, but I've encountered a problem:

Given a number of unit quaternions, I need to get a quaternion that when used to transform a vector will give a vector that is the average of the vector transformed by each quaternion individually. (with matrices I would simply add the matrices together and divide by the number of matrices)

Comment: This is not a solvable problem. Quaternions don't encode arbitrary linear transformations in 3d space; they only encode orthogonal transformations. But the "average" of several orthogonal transformations (in the sense of: for each vector, take all of its transforms and average them) is (in general) not orthogonal, so it is not obtainable by a quaternion. There might be some subtler notions of "average" that preserve orthogonality, but you can't get your notion of average.

Comment: All the possible arithmetics with quaternions are in this [page](http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/algebra/realNormedAlgebra/quaternions/index.htm). If you don't find it there then... good luck.

Comment: Have you considered looking at open source code for skeletal animation, rather than reinventing the wheel?  E.g., http://home.gna.org/cal3d/

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61146/averaging-quaternions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried Slerping the quaternions as suggested [here](http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=43261) but that didn't work for what I'm trying to do (model was distorted), so I simply ended up transforming the vectors by each quaternion and then doing an average (until I can find a better solution).

Comment: the slerping method in the link you provided actually worked for me. however the quaternions were relatively close.

Answer (score 79):

Contrary to popular belief in the computer graphics industry, there is a straightforward algorithm to solve this problem which is robust, accurate, and simple that comes from the aerospace industry.  It runs in time linear in the number of quaternions being averaged plus a (largish) constant factor.

Let *Q* = [*a*<sub>1</sub>*q*<sub>1</sub>, *a*<sub>2</sub>*q*<sub>2</sub>, ..., *a*<sub>*n*</sub>*q*<sub>*n*</sub>],

where *a*<sub>*i*</sub> is the weight of the *i*th quaternion, and *q*<sub>i</sub> is the *i*th quaternion being averaged, as a column vector.  *Q* is therefore a 4×*N* matrix.

The normalized eigenvector corresponding to the largest eigenvalue of *QQ*<sup>T</sup> is the weighted average.  Since *QQ*<sup>T</sup> is self-adjoint and at least positive semi-definite, fast and robust methods of solving that eigenproblem are available.  Computing the matrix-matrix product is the only step that grows with the number of elements being averaged.

See this [technical note in the Journal of Guidance, Control, and Dynamics from 2007](http://www.acsu.buffalo.edu/%7Ejohnc/ave_quat07.pdf), which is a summary paper of this and other methods.  In the modern era, the method I quoted above makes a good tradeoff for implementation reliability and robustness, and was already published in textbooks in 1978!

Comment: Jonathan's answer here is describing the same thing that is coded in the Unity3D link from Nathan's answer.  And minorlogic's answer includes a few nuances that are also captured in the Unity3D code example.  The Unity3D Wiki page (with code) seems like the most complete answer.

Comment: @GabeHalsmer: This is *not* true. The unity code is appropriate if the quaternions are sufficiently similar (it is nothing mor than an average plus negative quaternion checking). The referenced paper offers a totally different solution suited for all quaternions but with significantly higher computation costs.

Comment: Do weights a_1, a_2, .., a_n sum up to 1.0?

Comment: @Maksym Ganenko I tested it and it seems to be necessary.

Comment: I provide a Java implementation of this method in this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3435296/365886

Comment: Is there a mistake in this answer? I would put $a_i ^ {1/2}$ in your formulation such that $QQ^\intercal$ recovers the $a_i$. I say this because I see no squaring of the weights in eq 12 of your link http://www.acsu.buffalo.edu/~johnc/ave_quat07.pdf

Comment: In python here:  https://scikit-surgerycore.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/sksurgerycore/algorithms/averagequaternions.html#average_quaternions

Comment: @AlexanderSoare yes I agree, if using the Q.Q^T formulation, Q must be built from the square roots of the weights, not the weights themselves.

Answer (score 18):

Unfortunately it isn't terribly simple to do, but it is possible.  Here's a whitepaper explaining the math behind it: http://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20070017872_2007014421.pdf

Check out the Unity3D Wiki page (The below code sample is from the same article): http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Averaging_Quaternions_and_Vectors

```cs
//Get an average (mean) from more then two quaternions (with two, slerp would be used).
//Note: this only works if all the quaternions are relatively close together.
//Usage: 
//-Cumulative is an external Vector4 which holds all the added x y z and w components.
//-newRotation is the next rotation to be added to the average pool
//-firstRotation is the first quaternion of the array to be averaged
//-addAmount holds the total amount of quaternions which are currently added
//This function returns the current average quaternion
public static Quaternion AverageQuaternion(ref Vector4 cumulative, Quaternion newRotation, Quaternion firstRotation, int addAmount){

    float w = 0.0f;
    float x = 0.0f;
    float y = 0.0f;
    float z = 0.0f;

    //Before we add the new rotation to the average (mean), we have to check whether the quaternion has to be inverted. Because
    //q and -q are the same rotation, but cannot be averaged, we have to make sure they are all the same.
    if(!Math3d.AreQuaternionsClose(newRotation, firstRotation)){

        newRotation = Math3d.InverseSignQuaternion(newRotation);    
    }

    //Average the values
    float addDet = 1f/(float)addAmount;
    cumulative.w += newRotation.w;
    w = cumulative.w * addDet;
    cumulative.x += newRotation.x;
    x = cumulative.x * addDet;
    cumulative.y += newRotation.y;
    y = cumulative.y * addDet;
    cumulative.z += newRotation.z;
    z = cumulative.z * addDet;      

    //note: if speed is an issue, you can skip the normalization step
    return NormalizeQuaternion(x, y, z, w);
}

public static Quaternion NormalizeQuaternion(float x, float y, float z, float w){

    float lengthD = 1.0f / (w*w + x*x + y*y + z*z);
    w *= lengthD;
    x *= lengthD;
    y *= lengthD;
    z *= lengthD;

    return new Quaternion(x, y, z, w);
}

//Changes the sign of the quaternion components. This is not the same as the inverse.
public static Quaternion InverseSignQuaternion(Quaternion q){

    return new Quaternion(-q.x, -q.y, -q.z, -q.w);
}

//Returns true if the two input quaternions are close to each other. This can
//be used to check whether or not one of two quaternions which are supposed to
//be very similar but has its component signs reversed (q has the same rotation as
//-q)
public static bool AreQuaternionsClose(Quaternion q1, Quaternion q2){

    float dot = Quaternion.Dot(q1, q2);

    if(dot < 0.0f){

        return false;                   
    }

    else{

        return true;
    }
}
```

Also this post: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/86898-Average-quaternions

Comment: As a sidenote, here is a matlab implementation https://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/40098-tolgabirdal-averaging_quaternions

Comment: Can you please explain the logic behind ``AreQuaternionsClose``?

Comment: @GalDude33 The dot product of two vectors is also equal to the cosine of the angle between them times their lengths (see the "geometric definition" section of wikipedia's [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) article). The lengths are always positive, therefore the sign of the dot product is equal to the sign of the cosine of the angle between the "vectors", which in itself is sort of a complicated value *but* it will tell you if the two quaternions are ...

Comment: ... "pointed" in the same direction (if you were to consider them as 4-dimensional points rather than quaternions), which is just an approximate answer to the question "are the signs of each component inverted". If that makes sense. It's simple but somehow hard for me to explain in a comment, heh.

Comment: I.e.: If you imagine the quaternions as just plain old 4D vectors in 4D space, the dot product of them will be negative if they point in opposite directions (if the angle between them is > 90 degrees). Yeah. That's a simpler explanation. Maybe. Dot products have a lot of information hidden in them.

Answer (score 13):

[Here is the implementation](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/40098-tolgabirdal-averaging-quaternions) for MATLAB function that I use to average Quaternions for orientation estimation.
It is straightforward to convert the MATLAB to any other language, except that this particular method (Markley 2007) requires the calculation of the eigenvectors and eigenvalues. There are many libraries (including Eigen C++) that can do this for you.

You can read the description/header of the file to see the math from the original paper.

matlab file taken from http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/40098-tolgabirdal-averaging-quaternions :

```
% by Tolga Birdal
% Q is an Mx4 matrix of quaternions. weights is an Mx1 vector, a weight for
% each quaternion.
% Qavg is the weightedaverage quaternion
% This function is especially useful for example when clustering poses
% after a matching process. In such cases a form of weighting per rotation
% is available (e.g. number of votes), which can guide the trust towards a
% specific pose. weights might then be interpreted as the vector of votes 
% per pose.
% Markley, F. Landis, Yang Cheng, John Lucas Crassidis, and Yaakov Oshman. 
% "Averaging quaternions." Journal of Guidance, Control, and Dynamics 30, 
% no. 4 (2007): 1193-1197.
function [Qavg]=quatWAvgMarkley(Q, weights)

% Form the symmetric accumulator matrix
A=zeros(4,4);
M=size(Q,1);
wSum = 0;

for i=1:M
    q = Q(i,:)';
    w_i = weights(i);
    A=w_i.*(q*q')+A; % rank 1 update
    wSum = wSum + w_i;
end

% scale
A=(1.0/wSum)*A;

% Get the eigenvector corresponding to largest eigen value
[Qavg, ~]=eigs(A,1);

end
```

Comment: Why do you need `for i=1:M` loop? Can't you just weight values of `Q` and then compute `A=Q'*Q`?

Comment: @fdermishin: Yes, I tested that and it produces the same values with an error of around 10^-15. Plus it's probably a lot faster. Here's the code: `Q = (weights .* Q) ./ sum(weights); A = transpose(Q) * Q;`

Comment: Why scale is applied, it influence only eigenvalues magnitude. not eigenvectors
% scale
A=(1.0/wSum)*A;

Answer (score 5):

This is my implementation in python of Tolga Birdal's algorithm:

```
import numpy as np

def quatWAvgMarkley(Q, weights):
    '''
    Averaging Quaternions.

    Arguments:
        Q(ndarray): an Mx4 ndarray of quaternions.
        weights(list): an M elements list, a weight for each quaternion.
    '''

    # Form the symmetric accumulator matrix
    A = np.zeros((4, 4))
    M = Q.shape[0]
    wSum = 0

    for i in range(M):
        q = Q[i, :]
        w_i = weights[i]
        A += w_i * (np.outer(q, q)) # rank 1 update
        wSum += w_i

    # scale
    A /= wSum

    # Get the eigenvector corresponding to largest eigen value
    return np.linalg.eigh(A)[1][:, -1]
```

Comment: As an addendum, you can do this with `np.linalg.eigh(np.einsum('ij,ik,i->...jk', q, q, w))[1][:, -1]`, which is hundreds of times faster for large sets of quaternions. The scaling of the accumulator is all in the eigenvalues (not orthonormal eigenvectors) and can be omitted.

Comment: @reve_etrange: Is that line meant to replace the whole function, so that your `q` is the `Q` in the answer above (and `w` is `weights`)?

Comment: Ok, can confirm now that it indeed replaces the whole function and yields the same results up to the 7th decimal or so.

Comment: @ketz yep! Glad it helped, this is the right way to do it IMO. I think the differences at high precision are just different floating point errors and not algorithmic.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot add quaternions. What you can do is find a quaternion that rotates continuously between two angles, including halfway. Quaternion interpolation is known as "slerp" and has a wikipedia page. This is a very useful trick for animation. In some respects slerp is the primary reason for using quaternions in computer graphics.

Comment: You *can* add quaternions, but the sum of two unit quaternions will not be a unit quaternion.

Comment: But you _can_ average them, as Gouda shows above - http://stackoverflow.com/a/29315869/1200764

Answer (score 2):

There is a [technical report from 2001](http://www.soest.hawaii.edu/wessel/courses/gg711/pdf/Gramkow_2001_JMIV.pdf) which states that the mean is actually quite a good approximation, provided that the quaternions lie close together. (for the case of -q=q, you could just flip the ones that point in the other direction by pre multiplying them by -1, so that all of the quaternions involved life in the same half sphere.

An even better approach is sketched in [this paper from 2007](http://www.acsu.buffalo.edu/~johnc/ave_quat07.pdf), which involves using an SVD. This is the same paper that Nathan referenced. I would like to add that there is not just a C++, but also a [Matlab implementation](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/40098-averaging-quaternions). From executing the test script which comes with the matlab code, I can say that it gives quite good results for small pertubations (0.004 * uniform noise) of the quaternions involved:

```
qinit=rand(4,1);
Q=repmat(qinit,1,10);

% apply small perturbation to the quaternions 
perturb=0.004;
Q2=Q+rand(size(Q))*perturb;
```

Comment: This [same questions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61146/averaging-quaternions/) in math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

Since there are different approaches here, I wrote a Matlab script to compare them. These results seem to suggest that simply averaging and normalizing the quaternions (the approach from the unity wiki, called `simple_average` here) might be enough for cases where the quaternions are sufficiently similar and small deviations are acceptable.

Here's the output:

```
everything okay, max angle offset == 9.5843
qinit to average: 0.47053 degrees
qinit to simple_average: 0.47059 degrees
average to simple_average: 0.00046228 degrees
loop implementation to matrix implementation: 3.4151e-06 degrees
```

And here's the code:

```
%% Generate random unity quaternion
rng(42); % set arbitrary seed for random number generator
M = 100;
qinit=rand(1,4) - 0.5;
qinit=qinit/norm(qinit);
Qinit=repmat(qinit,M,1);

%% apply small perturbation to the quaternions 
perturb=0.05; % 0.05 => +- 10 degrees of rotation (see angles_deg)
Q = Qinit + 2*(rand(size(Qinit)) - 0.5)*perturb;
Q = Q ./ vecnorm(Q, 2, 2); % Normalize perturbed quaternions
Q_inv = Q * diag([1 -1 -1 -1]); % calculated inverse perturbed rotations

%% Test if everything worked as expected: assert(Q2 * Q2_inv = unity)
unity = quatmultiply(Q, Q_inv);
Q_diffs = quatmultiply(Qinit, Q_inv);
angles = 2*acos(Q_diffs(:,1));
angles_deg = wrapTo180(rad2deg(angles));
if sum(sum(abs(unity - repmat([1 0 0 0], M, 1)))) > 0.0001
    disp('error, quaternion inversion failed for some reason');
else
    disp(['everything okay, max angle offset == ' num2str(max(angles_deg))])
end

%% Calculate average using matrix implementation of eigenvalues algorithm
[average,~] = eigs(transpose(Q) * Q, 1);
average = transpose(average);
diff = quatmultiply(qinit, average * diag([1 -1 -1 -1]));
diff_angle = 2*acos(diff(1));

%% Calculate average using algorithm from https://stackoverflow.com/a/29315869/1221661
average2 = quatWAvgMarkley(Q, ones(M,1));
diff2 = quatmultiply(average, average2 * diag([1 -1 -1 -1]));
diff2_angle = 2*acos(diff2(1));

%% Simply add coefficients and normalize the result
simple_average = sum(Q) / norm(sum(Q));
simple_diff = quatmultiply(qinit, simple_average * diag([1 -1 -1 -1]));
simple_diff_angle = 2*acos(simple_diff(1));
simple_to_complex = quatmultiply(simple_average, average * diag([1 -1 -1 -1]));
simple_to_complex_angle = 2*acos(simple_to_complex(1));

%% Compare results
disp(['qinit to average: ' num2str(wrapTo180(rad2deg(diff_angle))) ' degrees']);
disp(['qinit to simple_average: ' num2str(wrapTo180(rad2deg(simple_diff_angle))) ' degrees']);
disp(['average to simple_average: ' num2str(wrapTo180(rad2deg(simple_to_complex_angle))) ' degrees']);
disp(['loop implementation to matrix implementation: ' num2str(wrapTo180(rad2deg(diff2_angle))) ' degrees']);
```

Answer (score 2):

[Check here](http://tbirdal.blogspot.com/) for my solution to weighted averaging as well as Lp median of quaternions.

Answer (score 1):

With quaternions you can do same thing, but with small correction: 
1. Negate quaternion before averaging if its dot product with previous sum is negative. 
2. Normalize average quaternion, a the end of averaging, if your library works with unit quaternions.

The average quaternion will represent approximately average rotation (max error about 5 degree).

WARNING: Average matrix of different orientations can be broken if rotations too different.

Answer (score 1):

Quaternions are not an ideal set of DOF to use for rotations when computing an unconstrained average.

Here is what I use most of the time (

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    internal static Vector3 ToAngularVelocity( this Quaternion q )
    {
        if ( abs(q.w) > 1023.5f / 1024.0f)
            return new Vector3();
            var angle = acos( abs(q.w) );
            var gain = Sign(q.w)*2.0f * angle / Sin(angle);

        return new Vector3(q.x * gain, q.y * gain, q.z * gain);
    }


    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    internal static Quaternion FromAngularVelocity( this Vector3 w )
    {
        var mag = w.magnitude;
        if (mag <= 0)
            return Quaternion.identity;
        var cs = cos(mag * 0.5f);
        var siGain = sin(mag * 0.5f) / mag;
        return new Quaternion(w.x * siGain, w.y * siGain, w.z * siGain, cs);

    }

    internal static Quaternion Average(this Quaternion refence, Quaternion[] source)
    {

        var refernceInverse = refence.Inverse();
        Assert.IsFalse(source.IsNullOrEmpty());
        Vector3 result = new Vector3();
        foreach (var q in source)
        {
            result += (refernceInverse*q).ToAngularVelocity();
        }

        return reference*((result / source.Length).FromAngularVelocity());
    }
     internal static Quaternion Average(Quaternion[] source)
    {
        Assert.IsFalse(source.IsNullOrEmpty());
        Vector3 result = new Vector3();
        foreach (var q in source)
        {
            result += q.ToAngularVelocity();
        }

        return (result / source.Length).FromAngularVelocity();
    }
     internal static Quaternion Average(Quaternion[] source, int iterations)
    {
        Assert.IsFalse(source.IsNullOrEmpty());
        var reference = Quaternion.identity;
        for(int i = 0;i < iterations;i++)
        {
            reference = Average(reference,source);

        }
        return reference;

    }`
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest implementation (with Numpy in Python>=3.6) of Markley's solution would be:

```py
import numpy as np
def q_average(Q, W=None):
    if W is not None:
        Q *= W[:, None]
    eigvals, eigvecs = np.linalg.eig(Q.T@Q)
    return eigvecs[:, eigvals.argmax()]
```

where `Q` is of size N-by-4. The resulting quaternion is already normalized.

In this case the weights are equal to 1 by default. Otherwise you can give a list of weights of size N (one per quaternion.)

That's it.

Comment: The version "limit" is due to the @ Operator which is introduced in PEP465. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465. The @ operator represents a Matrix Multiplication.

Comment: Note, you weight the Q instead of Q*Q' . so your weights is a square of different versions of algo

Answer (score 1):

Here is my PyTorch implementation for computing the average quaternion

```py
def mean(Q, weights=None):
    if weights is None:
        weights = torch.ones(len(Q), device=torch.device("cuda:0")) / len(Q)
    A = torch.zeros((4, 4), device=torch.device("cuda:0"))
    weight_sum = torch.sum(weights)

    oriented_Q = ((Q[:, 0:1] > 0).float() - 0.5) * 2 * Q
    A = torch.einsum("bi,bk->bik", (oriented_Q, oriented_Q))
    A = torch.sum(torch.einsum("bij,b->bij", (A, weights)), 0)
    A /= weight_sum

    q_avg = torch.linalg.eigh(A)[1][:, -1]
    if q_avg[0] < 0:
        return -q_avg
    return q_avg
```

I made use of the algorithm in http://tbirdal.blogspot.com/2019/10/i-allocate-this-post-to-providing.html which is "Averaging quaternions." by Markley, F. Landis, et al.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a GitHub Repo with the implementation of this suggested algorithmn :)
https://github.com/christophhagen/averaging-quaternions

Thanks and credits to christophhagen ofc ;)

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to comment on the solutions, but since I don't have 50 goo goo stars or whatever that are needed to be allowed to comment, I wanted to point out than when you're finding the max eigenvalue in the Markley method, I've found that the power iteration (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration) tends to be more robust than SVD with small rotations. At least with Eigen's JacobiSVD it crashes a lot.

Comment: so is this an answer or a comment in the place where only answers are supposed to go?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34756429)