# Average transformation matrix for a list of transformations

Tags: algorithm, math, matrix, 3d, transformation

I have multiple estimates for a transformation matrix, from mapping two point clouds to each other via [ICP (Iterative Closest Point)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_closest_point).

How can I generate the average transformation matrix for all these matrices?

Each matrix consists of a rigid translation and a rotation only, no scale or skew.

Ideally I would also like to calculate a weighted average, but an unweighted one is fine for now.

Averaging the translation vectors is of course trivial, but the rotations are problematic. One approach I found is averaging the individual base vectors for the rotations, but I am not sure that will result in a new orthonormal base, and the approach seems a little ad-hoc.

Comment: Orthonormality is a set of constraints; you should look into constrained least-squares solvers.  Unfortunately, these constraints are nonlinear (although they are well-behaved as nonlinear constraints go).  If you want an optimal solution, you will probably need some kind of iterative process, to find the valid rotation matrix closest to your input corpus.

Comment: I'm prolly not qualified to answer this. However, I have used Python lib from neuroscience to get the Euler equations for rotations (NiPY). The library is careful with the poles etc. Then, to get pseudo hermition matrix from non-linear transforms, you can perform the average in both directions and average that.

Answer (score 12):

Splitting the transformation in translation and rotation is a good start. Averaging the translation is trivial.

Averaging the rotation is not that easy. Most approaches will use quaternions. So you need to transform the rotation matrix to a quaternion.

The easiest way to approximate the average is a linear blending, followed by renormalization of the quaternion:

```
q* = w1 * q1 + w2 * q2 + ... + w2 * qn
normalize q*
```

However, this is only an approximation. The reason for that is that the combination of two rotations is not performed by adding the quaternions, but by multiplying them. If we convert quaternions to a logarithmic space, we can use a simple linear blend (because multiplication will become additions). Then transform the quaternion back to the original space. This is the idea of the Spherical Average (Buss 2001). If you're lucky, you find a library that supports log and exp of quaternions:

```
start with q* as above
do until convergence
    for each input quaternion i (index)
        diff = q[i] * inverse(q*)
        u[i] = log(diff, base q*)
    //Now perform the linear blend
    adapt := zero quaternion
    weights := 0
    for each input quaternion i
        adapt += weight[i] * u[i]
        weights += weight[i]
    adapt *= 1/weights
    adaptInOriginalSpace = q* ^ adapt    (^ is the power operator)
    q* = adaptInOriginalSpace * q*
```

You can define a threshold for `adaptInOriginalSpace`. If it is a very very small rotation, you can break the loop. This algorithm is proven to preserve geodesic distances on a sphere.

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising. As far as I understood it (a,b,c,d) and (-a,-b,-c,-d) represent the same quaternion, is there way to deal with that before adding them?

Comment: Well, for two quaternions you could check the dot product. If it's less than zero, negate one quaternion (otherwise the interpolation would go over the far side of the sphere). I'm not sure how to handle this with more than two quaternions. If you can make all dot products >= 0, it's great. However, there might be cases when this is not possible. But then interpolation might not be reasonable at all.

Answer (score 3):

If you have an existing lerp method, then there is a trivial solution:

```
count = 1
average_transform = Matrix.Identity(4)
for new_transform in list_of_matrices:
    factor = 1/count
    average_transform = lerp(average_transform, new_transform, factor)
    count += 1
```

This is only useful because lots more mathermatics packages have the ability to lerp matrices than to average lots of them.

Because I haven't come across this method elsewhere, here's an informal proof:

- If there is one matrix, use just that matrix (factor will equal 1 for first matrix)
- If there are two matrices, we need 50% of the second one (second factor is 50% so we lerp to half way between the existing first one and the new one)
- If there are three matrices we need 33% of each, or 66% of the average of the first two and 33% of the third. The lerp factor of 0.3333 makes this happen.

And so on.

I haven't tested extensively with matrices, but I've used this successfully as a rolling average for other datatypes.

Answer (score 2):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Quaternion will give you some elegant mathematics and a way to turn a rotation matrix into an angle of rotation round an axis of rotation. There will be two possible representations of each rotation, with different signs for both angle of rotation and axis of rotation.

You could convert everything and normalize them to have +ve angles of rotation, then work out the average angle of rotation and the average axis of rotation, renormalising this into a unit vector.

OTOH if your intention is to work out the most accurate possible estimate of the transformation, you need to write down some measure of the goodness of fit of any candidate transformation - a sum of squared errors is often mathematically convenient - and then solve an optimization problem to work out which transformation minimizes the sum of squared errors. This is at least easier to justify than taking an average of individually error-prone estimates, and may well be more accurate.

Comment: Averaging the angles and axes seems like an easy solution, but are you certain it is mathematically sound? It seems strange to average two angles if each of them pertains to different axes.

Comment: If the individual rotations are pretty much correct the differences between them should be very small which should make simple averaging a pretty good approximation of what you really need to do. I think the mathematically sound - or statistically efficient - thing to do is to write down the likelihood of the observations given the underlying transformation and then solve an optimization problem to find the underlying transformation that is associated with the highest log likelihood and solving a non-linear least squares problem is probably very close to this.

Answer (score 1):

The singular value decomposition (SVD) can be used here.

Take the SVD of the sum of the rotation matricies, and then the average rotation matrix is simply given by Ravg = UV'.

Comment: Is there a math explanation behind this answer? This seems very interesting.

Answer (score 0):

"sdfgeoff" I can't comment in your answer because I'm new here, but you are the most correct, I think. Beutifull and elegant solution, by the way. Would be perfect if you use Spherical Linear Interpolation (SLERP) with quaternions, instead of Linear Interpolation (LERP) because quaternions that map rotations (quaternions with norm 1) define a sphere in 4D, and interpolating between then is in fact interpolate between two point in a sphere surface.

With my experience from point cloud registration, I wuold like to say that this will not work. ICP don't return random rotations in the likehood of the correct rotation. You need to use a beter algorith to register you point clouds (Global Registration algorithms, like FPFH, 4PCS, K4PCS, BSC, FGR, etc). Or a better initial guess for the transformation. ICP will only give you totally wrong rotations (when stuck in local minima) or almost perfect rotations, when initialized with good initial transformations.
Conclusion: averaging it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking a look at ["Average" of multiple quaternions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374087/average-of-multiple-quaternions) for a more elaborate discussion on how to compute the average of rotations.