# How to calculate the average/best Rotation between two coordinate systems?

Tags: python, rotation, linear-algebra, least-squares, svd

Through a sensor I get the rotation between points in coordinate system A to points in coordinate system B. The measured rotations between the coordinate systems are not 100% identical due to the noise of the sensor.

How can I determine the average or optimal rotation matrix between the coordinate systems? Similar to this problem: [stackoverflow: Averaging Quatenion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374087/average-of-multiple-quaternions), but contrary to that I do not want to use Quaternions, but try some least square approach.

```
Given: Rba(n): Rotation matrix from a to b, measured at n different time points

Wanted: Rba optimal
```

My approach: Minimization of the squared distance.

First I define n random points in space and apply the rotations to these points.

[image: Application of the rotations on random points]

And now I can calculate the rotation by means of the Krabsch algorithm using singular value decomposition to minimize the square distance between the input points and the transformed points.
However, what I don't understand is that the calculated rotation matrix seems to be dependent on the input points. That is, I get different rotation matrices as a result for different input points, although the applied rotation matrices Rba(n) remain the same.
Why is that? And what is the right way?

Comment: Doesn't sound right. How many points are you using? What is your final error -- ie the sum of the squares of the lengths of the differences between the transformed -- with your computed R and T -- points and the original random points?

Comment: @dmuir I have round about 300 Points. And the square distance between the transformed points and the points on which I applied the optimized R is 0.0003. Its not that I get completely different results, but everytime I run it, the optimized Rotationmatrix is slightly different, which does not make sense to me..